# Редирект на сайт на Angular с POST данными

Tags: windows, angularjs, post

Имеем сайт на angular4. Имеем авторизацию по доменному имени на другом сервере на php, который перенаправляет пользователя после авторизации на вышеописанный сайт на angular4 с POST данными.

При попадании на сайт выдаётся сообщение:

> cannot POST и 404 (Not Found)

Видимо, нужна какая-то настройка роутера для пост параметров. Стандартный формат вида `<домен>/:<Параметр1>/:<Параметр2>` не работает в POST режиме.

Подскажите, как на angular принять POST параметры, если это возможно при заходе на сайт.

Вся история возникла оттого, что angular не видит windows-пользователя через `$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]`, который есть на PHP. Если есть решение этой проблемы, то тоже подойдет.